# How to post the subfigure capations on the right of figure?

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats, subcaption

How to post the subfigure capations on the right of figure?

[image: Like the potsed subfigure capations, it is my goal]

Like the posted subfigure capations, it is my goal. But the defaulted position is below, i have tried many times, did not achieve the goal.

Comment: Hello newcomer. Your question has been reported as too short and not-so-informative. Could you please update your question so that potential answers and visitors brought by Google search can clearly see what you are asking for? Questions fail to do so will be voted to close (i.e., people are not allowed to answer your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you need the `subfigure` package for the figure you show. The following is an extension to John Kormylo's answer.

```
% subcaptionprob.tex  SE 564314
% This is mainly from John Kormylo's answer

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5\baselineskip-0.5\height}% center baseline
    {\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=1in]{example-image}}%
  \parbox[c]{0.1\linewidth}{\subcaption{}}\par
\vspace{\baselineskip}
  \raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5\baselineskip-0.5\height}% center baseline
    {\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=1in]{example-image-golden}}%
  \parbox[c]{0.1\linewidth}{\subcaption{}}\par

\caption{Two (sub)figures}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It produces two images within one figure where their captions are at the right.

Answer (score 0):

This solution places the `\subcaption` in a separate `\parbox`.  Note that the widths should add up to `\linewidth`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5\baselineskip-0.5\height}% center baseline
    {\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=1in]{example-image}}%
  \parbox[c]{0.1\linewidth}{\subcaption{}}\par
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: There is an error, subcaption package can't be used in cooperation with the subfigure package.